# Why no line numbers in gVim help file?

Tags: vim

I've `:set number` in _vimrc, but when I open vim help using `:h <command>`, I don't see line numbers. I'll have to explicitly execute `:set number` to get line numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Vim has some specific logic when opening help files and resets certain options. Among them, there is the 'number' option.

You might be able to fix this using an BufWinEnter autocommand:

```
au BufWinEnter * if &bt is# 'help' | set nu | endif
```

(untested)

Comment: Is there a way to modify that specific logic?